# C++ Primer Mistake in counting

Tags: c++

I've got some problem with 7th exercise of 6th chapter from C++ Primer Plus book. Well, I think I made this exercise well, but my compiler think otherwise. The program should count number of vowels, consonants and other characters that start the word. The problem is that it counts vowels instead of consonants and consonants instead of vowels.

For example: if I enter "**a e o i u**" it says that I entered 5 words started by consonants.

Thanks in advance for explanation.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

char word[20];

int others=0;
int vowels=0;
int consonants=0;

int main()
{
    std::cout<<"Enter words (q to quit):";
    std::cin>>word;

    while(strcmp(word,"q"))
    {
        word[0]=tolower(word[0]);
        if(!isalpha(word[0]))
            others++;
        else if(word[0]!='a'&&word[0]!='e'&&word[0]!='i'&&word[0]!='o'&&word[0]!='u')
            consonants++;
        else vowels++;

        std::cin>>word;
    }
    std::cout<<vowels<<" words beginning with vowels\n";
    std::cout<<consonants<<" words beginning with consonants\n";
    std::cout<<others<<" others";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "For example: if I enter "a e o i u" it says that I entered 5 words started by consonants." -- That's not what's happening for me. Are you sure you recompiled your program after your last change, that you accurately copied the source code, and that you didn't make mistakes in entering the input?

Comment: It says "5 words beginning with vowels": [link](http://ideone.com/Z8Ef0k).

Comment: Ohh, sorry guys, I have no idea what was wrong, but now it does good. Well, I was using this code, and it was wrong, I think... Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: Works fine here - one vowel, two consonants, as expected: https://ideone.com/ASi56x

Comment: In any case you might add your own isvowel function. This will make the code easier to reason about and also easier to test.

Comment: Another thing: In most cases it is better to avoid fixed buffers. Overwise you might run into buffer overflows. Therefore you should probably change `word` into a `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I don't understand the term "fixed buffers", what do you mean? Do you mean that I overwrite word?

Comment: `std::cin` does not know that `word` can only take 19 characters + a terminating `\0` character. Yet it still will read in words with more than 19 characters overwritting whatever is stored in the memory before `word`. This is called a buffer overflow and is one of the most common security issues found in C and C++ program which often allows attackers to take over the computer. This can't happen if you use a `std::string` since that resizes automatically if more space is needed.

Comment: Thanks for advice again, now I understand. I have never thought about that this way.

Comment: Yeah it is something that can easily bite newcomers as well as experienced programmers. Therefore it is better to avoid such issues. I just thought of another issue when using an array. You did not initialise `word` via e.g. `char word[20] = {'\0'};` therefore its value is undefined. If you are on linux press `CTRL+D` when entering a word. This results in `EOF` and `std::cin` not reading in anything and keeping `word` unchanged. Now even though you did not read anything in you will most still likely enter the while-loop. `std::string` combined with an `std::string::empty` check avoids this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason here is when you type a e i o u 'they' fed in to std::cin as 5 different words. Because, cin in this situation takes space as the word separator, you will be prompted to enter new words after 5 iterations. So it's correct. If you enter a e i o u q then you will not be prompted again to enter any input since 6th word is q which is supposed to exit from your loop. So the behaviour is correct.

If you debug the program you can understand what's really going on.